# Generate a random number of non duplicated random number in [0, 1001] through a loop

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, random, plpgsql, stored-functions

I need to generate a random number of non duplicated random number in plpgsql. The non duplicated number shall fall in the range of [1,1001]. However, the code generates number exceeding 1001.

```
directed2number := trunc(Random()*7+1);
counter := directed2number
while counter > 0
loop
to_point := trunc((random() * 1/directed2number - counter/directed2number + 1) * 1001 +1);
...
...
counter := counter - 1;
end loop;
```

Comment: Homework? We have a tag for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand right

- You need a random number (**1 to 8**) of random numbers.
- The random numbers span **1 to 1001**.
- The random numbers need to be **unique**. None shall appear more than once.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.unique_rand_1001()
RETURNS SETOF integer AS
$body$
DECLARE
    nrnr    int := trunc(random()*7+1);  -- number of numbers
BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT (1000 * random())::integer + 1
    FROM   generate_series(1, nrnr*2)
    GROUP  BY 1
    LIMIT  nrnr;

END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT x.unique_rand_1001();
```

Numbers are made unique by the `GROUP BY`. I generate twice as many numbers as needed to provide enough numbers in case duplicates are removed. With the given dimensions of the task (max. 8 of 1001 numbers) it is astronomically unlikely that not enough numbers remain. Worst case scenario: viewer numbers are returned.

Comment: @KevinQ: You could start by phrasing your problem more clearly right now. Define what you need exactly. Edit your question or ask a new question. Don't put it in comments. I believe I answered this question as it was given.

Comment: You're right, however, your solution can't be applied to me. I tried to phrase myself better at: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326184/to-update-several-non-dupliated-rows-at-one-time-using-group-by)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't approach the problem that way in PostgreSQL.

From a software engineering point of view, I think I'd separate generating a random integer between x and y, generating 'n' of those integers, and guaranteeing the result is a set.

```
-- Returns a random integer in the interval [n, m].
-- Not rigorously tested. For rigorous testing, see Knuth, TAOCP vol 2.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_integer(integer, integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
   select cast(floor(random()*($2 - $1 +1)) + $1 as integer);
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

Then to select a single random integer between 1 and 1000,

```
select random_integer(1, 1000);
```

To select 100 random integers between 1 and 1000,

```
select random_integer(1, 1000)
from generate_series(1,100);
```

You can guarantee uniqueness in either application code or in the database. Ruby implements a `Set` class. Other languages have similar capabilities under various names.

One way to do this in the database uses a local temporary table. Erwin's right about the need to generate more integers than you need, to compensate for the removal of duplicates. This code generates 20, and selects the first 8 rows in the order they were inserted.

```
create local temp table unique_integers (
    id serial primary key,
    n integer unique
);

insert into unique_integers (n)
select random_integer(1, 1001) n
from generate_series(1, 20)
on conflict (n) do nothing;

select n 
from unique_integers
order by id
fetch first 8 rows only;
```

Comment: This won't be quite random, 1 and 1001 will be picked half as often as the other numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Tested and corrected. (When I say "something along these lines", you can bet that I haven't fully tested it.)

Comment: I want to note that for some intervals with negative numbers, this only returns negative numbers (e.g. "select random_integer(-1000,1000)"). Works good otherwise.

Comment: @Adé: Thanks. I think I need to rewrite this answer. From a software engineering standpoint, OP needs to separate generating a random integer between x and y, generating 'n' of those integers, and guaranteeing uniqueness. I'll give that some thought.